# Accessing a checkbox value on click in angular 2

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have this checkbox which i want to see if it checked through `ngModel` binding.
When i call `console.log(activeCheckbox);` i can see the `ngmodel` and its value property set to true in the console.
But when i call console.log(activeCheckbox.value); right after or seperately, the value is undefined?

Does anybody know what is happening here ?

```
<input #activeCheckbox="ngModel" (click)="checkIfActive(activeCheckbox)"
    [disabled]="pageStatus==4" [ngModel]="premiumContententPackage.active"    
    name="premiumContententPackageActive" id="premiumContententPackageActive" 
    type="checkbox" >

checkIfActive(activeCheckbox){
   console.log(activeCheckbox);
   console.log(activeCheckbox.value);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can listen to input change event and get the state, or event assign it to any variable

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" (change)="changed($event)"/>


changed(evt) {
    this.isChecked = evt.target.checked;
    alert(evt.target.checked)
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/rSxR6f88NHMBKoqDtw08?p=preview

**EDIT**: The reason your code cannot see the change is because `click` and `change` events are different - click event will get called before the input changed. See https://plnkr.co/edit/rSxR6f88NHMBKoqDtw08?p=preview

Comment: `click` and `change` events are different, click event will get called before the input changed https://plnkr.co/edit/rSxR6f88NHMBKoqDtw08?p=preview